# An attempt to Prove (or Disprove)

Tags: geometry

I just found out from my calculations the following:

- Corresponding a given length of a one-dimensional element, if a two-dimensional lamina, (having same boundary length as the length of the one-dimensional element) is  constructed, then a circle has the largest area.
- Corresponding a given area of a two-dimensional lamina, if a three-dimensional structure,(having same surface-area as the area of the two-dimensional lamina) is  constructed, then a sphere has the largest volume.

Now let us call length, width, height as "parameters" of the first, second, and third dimensions.

Then, I state:

- Any 1-D element has only one parameter-length.
- Any 2-D lamina has two parameters-length, width. Product of these gives Area of lamina.
- Any 3-D structure has three parameters-length, width, height. Product of these gives Volume of structure.
- Thus, mathematically, when constructing an "n"-dimensional entity, from an "n-1"-dimensional entity, the product of all n-dimensions is the greatest for that entity, that consists all of its "boundary-points", in n-dimensional space, equidistant from the origin of the n-dimensional coordinates-system.

I guess that this (the last statement) could be proved (or rather, disproved) using principles of mathematical-induction, but that's just a mere guess.

Please help.

Comment: Could you tell a bit how did you calculated that the circle has the maximum area for a given parameter?

Comment: Crossposted from http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/119091/2451

Comment: LOL, looks like someone from Phys.SE downvoted your question here.

Comment: @user31782: I guess I forgot to mention my intuition. I just carried out for pairs of circle-square, and sphere-cube. I had come across while studying Euclidean-geometry that for a given perimeter, the circle possesses the largest-area. With a bit of intuition, I dared to proceed regarding sphere-cube, and from there, to n-dimensional Euclidean space. I guess that's why there's lack of precision in my question, as user111187 has pointed out.

Answer (score 0):

This result (reformulated in a proper way, but it is what you mean) is known as (a generalization of) the isoperimetric inequality. For example, see [this webpage](http://planetmath.org/ndimensionalisoperimetricinequality) where it is proved using calculus of variations (not induction).